# Settings bundle: how to create a clickable button that shows a text field?

Tags: xcode, settings.bundle, root.plist

How can I create a Root.plist file that has a group with some Title, then a clickable button  with some caption, and once that button is clicked, a new window "pops in" with some long text field? Something like "About" option for applications --> the about button links to a long text field.

I tried creating a group, then a multi-value, and to the multi-value's "Titles" array I added a String item with the text. However that text is clickable and I want it to look like text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add a child-pane and not a multi-value.

Add this node to the root.plist file:

Type
   PSChildPaneSpecifier
    Key
    About
    Title
    About
    File
    About

And then create an About.plist file (add it to the settings.bundle from the Finder: view package content and then add the file manually.

The file should look like this:

Strings Filename
    About
    PreferenceSpecifiers
    
        
            Title
            
            Type
            PSGroupSpecifier
            FooterText
            Bla Bla Bla